# page loading animation not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I have simple javascript which shows and hides div with loading image.
On chrome(14), ti seems working fine since the loading image shows up at every page refresh.
However, IE(9) and FF(7) show the image at first page call only. After it displays the image once, it is not showing the image anymore even though the page still loading content.

```
<body>

<div id="loadingDiv">
    <div id="loadingImageDiv">
        <p><img src="./imgs/loading_1.gif" /></p>
        <p><b>Please Wait</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
....

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "some.json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
              function(json) {
             $.each(json, function(i) {
            ....
            },
        complete: function() { $("#loadingDiv").hide(); }
   });
});
```

The content is being loaded by ajax call in jquery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Got a JSFiddle we can test your claims on?

Comment: Yes, where is the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using either `success` or `complete` but not both.  So `complete` would need to look something like this:

```
complete: function(xhr, status) {
              switch(status) {
                  case "success":
                      $.each(xhr.responseText.parseJSON(), function(i) {
                          ....
                      };
                      break;
                  default:
                      break;
              }
              $("#loadingDiv").hide();
          }
```

I haven't tested that, but I **think** it's right.  Something to try, at least.